# Geodesic tangent vector in a Riemannian 4-space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

I am doing a question in Lewis Ryder's introduction to General relativity. I am very close to the answer but not quite there.

**The question is:**

> A Riemannian 4-space has metric
>   $$ds^2 = e^{2\sigma}[(dx^1)^2+(dx^2)^2+(dx^3)^2+(dx^4)^2]$$
>   where $\sigma =\sigma(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)$. if $t^\mu$ is the unit tangent to the geodesic prove that, along the geodesic,
>   $$\frac{dt^\mu}{\delta \sigma}+2(\sigma_\nu t^\nu)t^\mu=\sigma^\mu$$
>   where $\sigma_\mu=\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial x^\mu}$.

**What I have so far:**
$$g_{\mu\nu}=e^{2\sigma}diag(1,1,1,1)$$
From the equation of a geodesic,
$$\frac{dt^\mu}{ds}+\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\nu\kappa}t^\nu t^\kappa=0$$
Since the metric is diagonal, for $\mu\neq\nu\neq\kappa$
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\nu\kappa}=0$$
for $\mu=\nu\neq\kappa$
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\mu\kappa}=\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\kappa\mu}=\sigma_\kappa$$
for $\mu\neq\nu=\kappa$
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\kappa\kappa}=-\sigma_\mu$$
and for $\mu=\nu=\kappa$
$$\Gamma^\mu_{\,\,\mu\mu}=\sigma_\mu$$
So for $\kappa\neq\mu$ the geodesic equation becomes:

$\frac{dt^\mu}{ds}+\sigma_\mu t^\mu t^\mu-\sigma_\mu t^\kappa t^\kappa +2\sigma_\kappa t^\mu t^\kappa=0$

$\frac{dt^\mu}{ds}-\sigma_\mu t^\nu t^\nu +2\sigma_\nu t^\mu t^\nu=0\quad....\nu=1,2,3,4$

where 
$$t^\nu t^\nu=\sqrt{(dx^1)^2+(dx^2)^2+(dx^3)^2+(dx^4)^2}=e^{-\sigma}\text{ and } \sigma_\mu=\sigma^\mu g_{\mu\nu}$$
Hence
$$\frac{dt^\mu}{ds}+2(\sigma_\nu t^\nu) t^\mu=\sigma^\mu$$

As you can see it is very close to the final answer but not quite it. Part of my confusion is in the $\frac{dt}{\delta\sigma}$ term, as I am not sure what the $\delta\sigma$ signifies.

Comment: It may just be a typo in the book.

Comment: Yeah I was starting to think so myself, it doesn't make much sense otherwise